# DB2 DDL Parser using ANTLR 3

Tags: db2, antlr

I am trying to build ANTLR 3 grammar for DB2 DDL statement (CREATE TABLE) and I am finding Decision can match input such as "DATA" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2. I am following DB2 DDL Documentation document.

I have exactly mapped the syntax diagrams to the grammar. But the problem is that there are some optional clauses and path can get to the same point and hence multiple alternatives. I have used backtrack option but I want some other solution of this. Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Please have a look at my grammar:

```
unit:
create_table_statement
;

create_table_statement:
create_table_statement_rest
;

create_table_statement_rest:
  CREATE TABLE ID create_table_opts
  organize_by_items?
  DATA CAPTURE (NONE|CHANGES) in_tbspc_cyc
  tablespace_opts? distribution_clause?
  partitioning_clause? compress_ny_val_compression
  with_restrict_on_drop? not_logged_init?
  ccsid_ascii_unicode? (SECURITY POLICY name)?
  (OPTIONS LPAREN ADD name name (COMMA name name)* RPAREN)?
;

with_restrict_on_drop:
WITH RESTRICT ON DROP
;

not_logged_init:
  NOT LOGGED INITIALLY
;

ccsid_ascii_unicode:
  CCSID (ASCII|UNICODE)
;

create_table_opts:
  element_list
  |OF name typed_table_opts?
  |materialized_query_definition
  |staging_table_definition
  |LIKE name copy_opts? 
;

organize_by_items:
  ORGANIZE BY (dimensions_item|key_sequence_items)
;

dimensions_item:
  DIMENSIONS? LPAREN ID (COMMA ID)* RPAREN
;

key_sequence_items:
  KEY SEQUENCE sequence_key_spec
;

sequence_key_spec:
  LPAREN seq_key_spec_one (COMMA seq_key_spec_one) RPAREN (ALLOW|DISALLOW) OVERFLOW (PCTFREE DIGIT)?
;

seq_key_spec_one:
  ID (STARTING FROM? CONSTANT)? ENDING AT? DIGIT
;

in_tbspc_cyc:
  IN (name (COMMA name)*) NO? CYCLE?
;

tablespace_opts:
  //tablespace_opt_one? 
  (INDEX IN name)? (LOG IN name (COMMA name)*)?
;

distribution_clause:
  DISTRIBUTE BY distribute_by_opts
;

distribute_by_opts:
  distribution_item_one
  |distribution_item_two
;

distribute_by:
  DISTRIBUTE BY
;

distribution_item_one:
  HASH LPAREN ID (COMMA ID)* RPAREN
;

distribution_item_two:
  REPLICATION
;

tablespace_opt_one:
  INDEX IN name LOG IN name
;

element_list:
  LPAREN
     element_list_items (COMMA element_list_items)*
  RPAREN
;

materialized_query_definition:
  (ID (COMMA ID)*)? AS LPAREN fullselect RPAREN materialized_query_table_opts
;

staging_table_definition:
  (LPAREN name (COMMA name)* RPAREN) FOR name PROPAGATE IMMEDIATE
;

fullselect:

;

materialized_query_table_opts:
  WITH NO DATA copy_opts? | refreshable_table_opts
;

element_list_items:
  column_definition|referential_constraint|check_constraint
;

column_definition:
  name data_type? column_opts?
;

copy_opts:
  ((INCLUDING|EXCLUDING) COLUMN? DEFAULTS)? (EXCLUDING|INCLUDING) IDENTITY (COLUMN ATTRIBUTES)?
;

refreshable_table_opts:
  DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH (DEFERRED|IMMEDIATE) (ENABLE|DISABLE) QUERY OPTIMIZATION (MAINTAINED BY (SYSTEM|USER|FEDERATED_TOOL))?
;

data_type:
  SMALLINT
  |INTEGER|INT
  |BIGINT
  |FLOAT (LPAREN DIGIT RPAREN)?
  |REAL
  |DOUBLE PRECISION?
  |(DECIMAL|DEC|NUMERIC|NUM) (LPAREN DIGIT (COMMA INTEGER)? RPAREN)?
  |(dt_char|dt_vchar|LONG VARCHAR) (FOR BIT DATA)?
  |((BLOB|BINARY LARGE OBJECT)|(CLOB|(CHARACTER|CHAR) LARGE OBJECT|DBCLOB) (LPAREN DIGIT (K|M|G) RPAREN)?)
  |GRAPHIC (LPAREN DIGIT RPAREN)
  |VARGRAPHIC (LPAREN DIGIT RPAREN)
  |LONG VARGRAPHIC
  |DATE
  |TIME
  |TIMESTAMP
  |XML
  //|name
  //added name instead of the two below but it would be replaced
  //|distinct_type_name
  //|structured_type_name
  |REF name
  |(LPAREN SYSPROC DOT RPAREN)? DB2SECURITYLABEL
;

dt_char :   (CHARACTER|CHAR)(LPAREN DIGIT RPAREN)?
    ;
dt_vchar    :
    (VARCHAR|((CHAR|CHARACTER) VARYING))LPAREN DIGIT RPAREN 
    ;
distinct_type_name
:   
name
;
structured_type_name
:
name    
;

column_opts:
  column_options_items+
; 

column_options_items:
  NOT NULL
  |lob_opts
  |SCOPE name
  |((CONSTRAINT name)? ((PRIMARY KEY|UNIQUE)| references_clause|(check_condition constraint_attributes)))
  |generated_column_spec
  |(INLINE LENGTH DIGIT)
  |(COMPRESS SYSTEM DEFAULT)
  |(COLUMN SECURED WITH ID)
;

lob_opts:
  NOT? LOGGED NOT? COMPACT
;

generated_column_spec:
  default_clause|generated_by_identity|generated_by_exp
;

default_clause:
  WITH? DEFAULT default_values?
;

default_values:
  default_values_items
  |cast_function LPAREN default_values_items RPAREN
  |NULL
;

default_values_items
:
constant
|datetime_special_register
|user_special_register
|CURRENT SCHEMA 
;

datetime_special_register:
  CURRENT DATE
  |CURRENT TIME
  |CURRENT TIMESTAMP
;

user_special_register:
  CURRENT USER
  |SESSION_USER
  |SYSTEM_USER
;

cast_function:
  //needs to be figured out
;

generated_by_identity:
  GENERATED (ALWAYS|(BY DEFAULT)) identity_opts?
;

identity_opts:
  AS IDENTITY LPAREN identity_options_items (identity_options_items)* RPAREN
;

identity_options_items:
  START WITH DIGIT
  |INCREMENT BY DIGIT
  |NO MINVALUE
  |MINVALUE DIGIT
  |NO MAXVALUE
  |MAXVALUE DIGIT
  |NO CYCLE
  |CYCLE
  | (NO CACHE | CACHE DIGIT)//cache 20 needs to be seen
  |NO ORDER
  |ORDER
;

generated_by_exp:
  GENERATED ALWAYS? AS generation_expression
;

generation_expression:
  //needs to be figured out
;

unique_constraint:
  (CONSTRAINT name)? (UNIQUE|PRIMARY KEY) LPAREN name (COMMA name)* RPAREN
;

referential_constraint:
  (CONSTRAINT ID)? FOREIGN KEY LPAREN ID (COMMA ID)* RPAREN references_clause
;

references_clause:
  REFERENCES  name (LPAREN ID (COMMA ID)* RPAREN)? rule_clause constraint_attributes
;

rule_clause:
  ON DELETE (NO ACTION | RESTRICT|CASCADE|SET NULL) ON UPDATE (NO ACTION|RESTRICT)
;

check_constraint:
  (CONSTRAINT name) CHECK check_condition constraint_attributes
;

check_condition:
  search_condition|functional_dependency
;

constraint_attributes:
  NOT? ENFORCED (ENABLE|DISABLE) QUERY OPTIMIZATION 
;

search_condition:
  //needs to be done
;

functional_dependency:
  (ID | (LPAREN ID (COMMA ID)* RPAREN)) DETERMINED BY (ID | (LPAREN ID (COMMA ID)* RPAREN))
;

typed_table_opts:
  (HIERARCHY name|under_clause)? typed_element_list?
;

typed_table_options_item2:
  under_clause
;

under_clause:
  UNDER name INHERIT SELECT PRIVILEGES
;

typed_element_list:
  LPAREN typed_element_list_items (COMMA typed_element_list_items)* RPAREN
;

typed_element_list_items:
  oid_column_definition | with_opts | unique_constraint | check_constraint
;

oid_column_definition:
  REF IS name USER GENERATED
;

with_opts:
  name WITH OPTIONS column_opts
;

partitioning_clause:
  part_by_range range_partition_spec 
;

part_by_range:
  PARTITION BY RANGE?
;
compress_ny_val_compression:
COMPRESS (NO|YES) (VALUE COMPRESSION)?
;

range_partition_spec:
  LPAREN partition_expression (COMMA partition_expression)* RPAREN LPAREN partition_element (COMMA partition_element)* RPAREN
;

partition_element:
  partition_boundry_element
  |start_with_boundry_spec
;

partition_boundry_element:
  (PARTITION name)? boundary_spec (IN name)?
;

start_with_boundry_spec:
  boundary_spec EVERY (duration_with_paren|duration_without_paren)
;

duration_with_paren:
  LPAREN constant duration_label RPAREN
;

duration_without_paren:
  constant duration_label
;

partition_expression:
  NULLS (LAST|FIRST)
;

boundary_spec:
  boundary_spec_path_one|boundary_spec_path_two
;

boundary_spec_path_one:
  starting_clause ending_clause
;

boundary_spec_path_two:
  ending_clause
;

starting_clause:
  STARTING FROM? (starting_ending_with_repeat|starting_ending_without_repeat) (INCLUSIVE|EXCLUSIVE)
;

ending_clause:
  ENDING AT? (starting_ending_with_repeat|starting_ending_without_repeat) (INCLUSIVE|EXCLUSIVE)
;

starting_ending_with_repeat:
  LPAREN starting_ending_clause_values (COMMA starting_ending_clause_values)* RPAREN
;

starting_ending_without_repeat:
  starting_ending_clause_values
;

duration_label:
  YEAR|YEARS|MONTH|MONTHS|DAY|DAYS|HOUR|HOURS|MINUTE|MINUTES|SECOND|SECONDS|MICROSECOND|MICROSECONDS
;

starting_ending_clause_values:
  constant|MINVALUE|MAXVALUE
;

constant:
  DIGIT
;

name    :   ID;

///////////////////////////////////////////////END PARSER RULES///////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////LEXER RULES///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

WS      :   ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' )+   { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;

COMMA   
  :  ','  
  ;  

EQUAL:
       '=';
STRING_LITERAL
```

:
         ('n'|'u')?'\''(  ~('\'') | '\'\'' )*  '\'' ;

```
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
;
DIGIT : '0'..'9'+
;
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to format your code a bit better.  I suspect you need to indent bits of it slightly further than you did.

Comment: The error you describe appears during cross-rule analysis of the entire grammar. It is impossible to help without seeing the full grammar.